# How to avoid normalization of rational numbers in boost?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using Boost.Rational 1.46. According to its [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/rational/rational.html),

> The final fundamental operation is normalizing a rational. This operation is performed **whenever a rational is constructed (and assigned in place)**. All other operations are careful to maintain rationals in a normalized state. Normalization costs the equivalent of one gcd and two divisions.

For an application with intensive usage of relatively small rational values (and therefore small integer numbers), normalization is too expensive to be done all the time. Is there a way of avoiding this, or just forcing only at certain moments?

Comment: Think twice about doing this. Because the intermediate results can overflow the underlying integer type very easily after a few operations. First, as the numbers (numerator and denominator) get bigger  then it is more costly *later* to simplify the equation (so the optimization is lost). Second, switching to multi or unlimited precision integer also suffers from the same problems since you will need to use more and more memory after several operations. Anyway I am interested to know what was your experience after all.

Comment: This was more than 3 years ago, but we did have a use where we didn't need normalization, and, what's more, we would only multiply once so we wouldn't accumulate bits, so to speak. Also, we were using GCC's int128 as the integer type, where our true input was int32, so we were guaranteed not to have overflows, etc. However, in the end we managed to modify an algorithm to rely on integer arithmetic only.

Comment: It makes sense, if the denominator is a priori bounded, it is always possible to solve the problem with pure integral (possible multiprecision) arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

The invariant of the boost rational numbers is that they are always normalized (see reference quoted in your question).  Thus if you want to use unnormalized rationals, you cannot use the boost implementation.

Comment: Well, yes, that's why I'm asking how to do it. A modified version would be fine, though an optional normalization would be better.

Comment: YOu could roll your own implementation.  To not start from scratch, you can take a look at [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1718.pdf) (referenced from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3363.html)).  The paper describes a rational library with the option of trurning off normalization.  I'm not aware of any (other) library that offers that capability.